# Google chrome extension webrequest intercept

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that will convert google scholar endnote file to a citation format.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(reqObj){
    if (reqObj.tabId != -1){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", reqObj.url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState == 4){
                parseEndnote(xhr.responseText); //Parse the endnote and create the citation
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
        return {redirectUrl : "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,Citation%20Created"}
    }
},
{urls : ["*://*/scholar.enw*"]}, 
["blocking"]
);
```

Problem:

I have to redirect to a data url. I would prefer the click action to be *cancelled*.

Returning `{cancel : true}` results in the user being redirected to a "This-page-was-blocked-by-an-extension generic chrome page"

Any ideas as to how to work around this one?

Comment: Any reason you can't inject a content script and `return false` (or `e.preventDefault()`) in an event listener bound to the relevant links you want to stop?

Comment: @apsillers May be that is the way to go. I had just hoped that some simple global code without message passing would suffice. I am open to further suggestions though... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of following a link goes like this:

1. User performs a click (or keypress) action on the link
2. Event handler code runs for that event
3. The click is successful, and the browser undertakes an HTTP request for the resource

   - the `onBeforeRequest` listeners run
   - other `webRequest` listeners run, etc.

You're trying to stop the click event in step 2, but your `webRequest` code doesn't run until step 3. The very fact that your `webRequest` code is running at all means that some link-activation event (`click` or `keypress`) has already succeeded.

You'll need to inject a content script into the page to add event-canceling listeners directly to the links you want to stop (e.g., with `return false` or `preventDefault`).

Comment: Thanks, this was my first chrome extension (a hobby project). I have injected a content script now